# why MainActivity have ListaPaises=null and why setOnItemSelectedListener doesnt work?

Tags: android

This app try to receive a .csv from a url. then we get a list of countries and try to show it on a spinner. i cant understand why `ListaPaises` is null in `MainActivity` and why `setonitemselectedlistener` doesnt work.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {

    private static final String UPDATE_URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv.";
    private static final String UPDATE_PAISES = "http://www.atc.uniovi.es/grado/4at/misc/currencies.csv";
    private Button button;
    private Button button2;
    public double mEuroToDollar = 1.34;
    public static List<String> ListaPaises = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText mEditTextEuros;
    EditText mEditTextDollars;
    public String PaisSEL1;
    public String PaisSEL2;
    String [] datos = {"OPC1", "OPC2","OPC3"};
    Spinner sp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GetPaises().execute(UPDATE_PAISES);


        List<String> pruebas = ListaPaises;




        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       // Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ListaPaises);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        //sp2.setAdapter(adapter);


        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int position, long id){
              PaisSEL1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){


            }
        });











        mEditTextEuros = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditTextDollars = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);








        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conversion realizada",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ConvertToDollars(mEditTextEuros, mEditTextDollars, mEuroToDollar);
            }
        });
        /*button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Convierte a Euros",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ConvertToEuros(mEditTextEuros, mEditTextDollars, mEuroToDollar);

            }
        });*/


    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    // Se llama cuando el usuario pulsa el botÃ³n


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void ConvertToDollars(EditText mEditTextEuros, EditText mEditTextDollars,
                        double mEuroToDollar) {

        String StringSource = mEditTextEuros.getText().toString();

        double NumberSource;
        try {
            NumberSource = Double.parseDouble(StringSource);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return;
        }
        double NumberDestination = NumberSource * mEuroToDollar;

        String StringDestination = Double.toString(NumberDestination);

        mEditTextDollars.setText(StringDestination);
    }
    public void ConvertToEuros(EditText mEditTextDollars, EditText mEditTextEuros,
                               double mEuroToDollar) {

        String StringSource = mEditTextDollars.getText().toString();

        double NumberSource;
        try {
            NumberSource = Double.parseDouble(StringSource);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return;
        }
        double NumberDestination = NumberSource / mEuroToDollar;

        String StringDestination = Double.toString(NumberDestination);

        mEditTextEuros.setText(StringDestination);
    }



    public class GetPaises extends AsyncTask<String, List<String>, List<String>> {
        public void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {




        }



        public List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {


            List<String> ListaMonedas= getCurrencyRateUsdRate(urls[0]);


            //return String.valueOf(getCurrencyRateUsdRate(urls[0]));

            return ListaMonedas;


        }

        private List<String> getCurrencyRateUsdRate(String url) {

            String auxiliar = null;
            try {
                auxiliar = readStream(openUrl("http://www.atc.uniovi.es/grado/4at/misc/currencies.csv"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<String> auxiliar2 = parseDataFromNetwork(auxiliar);



            return auxiliar2;
        }

        protected String readStream(InputStream urlStream) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            return total.toString();
        }

        protected InputStream openUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            return conn.getInputStream();
        }
        private List<String> parseDataFromNetwork(String data) {

            String[] lineDataaux = data.split("country");
            String lineDataaux2 = lineDataaux[1];
            String[] lineData = lineDataaux2.split(",");
            List<String> CodigosMonedas=new ArrayList();
            for (int i=2 ; i<lineData.length ; i=i+4){

                ListaPaises.add(lineData[i]);

            }

            //if (lineData.length != CSV_FIELDS) {
            //   return null;
            //}
            return CodigosMonedas;
        }
    }
    }
```

In this point of `MainActivity`, `ListaPaises` should be and array of 730 elements but is null and `setonitemselected` doesnt work:

```
new GetPaises().execute(UPDATE_PAISES);


    List<String> pruebas = ListaPaises;




    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   // Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ListaPaises);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    //sp2.setAdapter(adapter);


    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int position, long id){
          PaisSEL1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
       }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){


        }
    });
```

The csv file is this:
http://gyazo.com/657f5dffc5092cc6d623fb94de3c87ba

Comment: Could you narrow down your code to the specific area you have a question about, such as the CSV import please.

Comment: Added the csv image and the part of the code where doesnt work.

Comment: If you use a `AsyncTask` to initialize your ListaPaises object, you probably need to use the `onPostExecute()` method to use the values initialized in the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: I dont understand what taht means. im so noob sorry :(

Comment: You mean declare ListaPaises in doInBackground?

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You initialize ListaPaises in a backgroud thread using your implementation of a AsyncTask subclass (GetPaises). AsyncTask has another method, `onPostExecute()`, this method is executed after doInBackground() finish. You probably want to implement  this method, at this point ListaPaises should be initialized and you could initialize your Spinner and listeners.

Answer (score 1):

ListaPaises was initialized in a wrong place. It should be initialized in AsyncTask class.